# How to turn a list into a dynamic lambda?

Tags: python, lambda

I have a list of dimensions, example below:

```
dimensions = ['dimension1', 'dimension2', 'dimension3']
```

And I want to be able to dynamically translate that list into this line of code:

```
key = lambda x: (x['dimension1'], x['dimension2'], x['dimension3]')
```

So essentially I'm looking for a function that takes a list of dimensions and outputs that line of code for any given number of dimensions.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter

Comment: Although itemgetter doesn't make a tuple if it's only retrieving one item... that doesn't matter if you're using the function as a sort key, but it could matter for other cases.

Comment: You could also use a list comprehension: `key = lambda x: tuple(x[d] for d in dimensions)`

Answer (score 0):

As [pointed out](https://1%20hour%20ago) by @user2357112 in the comments, what you want is almost exactly what [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) does:

```
from operator import itemgetter

dimensions = 'dimension1', 'dimension2', 'dimension3'
key = itemgetter(*dimensions)

data = dict(dimension1=1, dimension2=2, dimension3=42)

print(key(data))  # -> (1, 2, 42)
```